# Mongo db search priority

Tags: mongodb

In mongo collection

I have records like

```
{
name:"test app app"
}
{
name:"app"
}
{
name:"apple"
}
{
name:"app1"
}
```

Now i need to search with **app** keyword

I want to fectch records like

Exact match first

```
{
name:"app"
}
{
name:'app1'
}

{
name:"apple"
}
{
name:"test app app", 
}
```

Priority:

1. Exact match first
2. Next starts with
3. Next contains

I need to search on multiple fileds.

Answer (score 0):

You use this code for search :

```
db.collection.find().sort( { name: -1 } )
```